# How Do I Programmatically Check for a Program's Existence?

Tags: unix, language-agnostic

Let's say I'm writing something that depends on external programs, like `svn`.  How do I check for their existence automatically, so I can print a helpful error message when they're absent?  Iterating through `PATH` is possible, but hardly elegant and efficient.  Are there cleaner solutions?

I've seen this behavior in a bootstrapping script, though I can't remember where.  It looked a little like this:

```
checking for gcc... yes
```

Comment: When you say "program" exactly what do you mean? A binary file? Are you talking about linux?

Comment: @MostyMostacho Anything callable via `system()` in C or via the command line, basically.  And yes, Linux/Unix.  (See tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can use the `type` builtin:

```
$ type -f svn
svn is /usr/bin/svn
```

If you want to use it in a script:

```
$ type -f svn &>/dev/null; echo $?
0
$ type -f svn_doesnt_exist &>/dev/null; echo $?
1
```

Comment: any benefit of this over `which`? That's what I'd normally use.

Comment: @SanjayManohar `which` is a program, but `type` is a shell builtin.  Furthermore, `type` can also find stuff like functions and can cut through aliases.  For example, if you alias a command, `type` will tell you the alias whereas `which` will fail to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to actually call it.

It makes most sense to call it with `-V` or whatever else option that makes the program report its version; most of the time you want the program to be at least such-and-such version.

If your program is a shell script, `which` is your friend, too.

Comment: -1: Definitely don't blindly run commands unless you are absolutely sure that running the program is not deleterious.

Comment: @FooBah: If you don't have access to package system, etc, you can only see if an executable of given name is present on `PATH` or not. An attempt to execute will search `PATH` anyway, and either run the command or return an error. What security or robustness will you buy doing this by hand?